# Two circuit breakers, how to determine which one jumps

Tags: electrical

In my home I have two sets of circuit breakers. One is upstairs in my home, and another is downstairs in a shared area of the residence I live in. When too many appliances are connected one of the two circuit breakers goes off (the switches pop down).

My question is, what determines whether it is the one upstairs that goes off or the one upstairs?

Does it depend on the circuit? Both circuit breakers service my apartment alone.

Thanks.!

Upstairs circuit breaker:
[image: upstairs circuit breaker]

Downstairs circuit breaker:
[image]

Comment: Is the tripping breaker downstairs a sort of master breaker that services several upstairs circuits? What is the amperage rating of the downstairs breaker that trips (e.g., 20 A, 30 A, 40 A, . . . )? Is the downstairs breaker a "double-pole breaker" which would have two handles linked together? What is the amperage rating of the upstairs breakers which trip. e.g. 15 A, 20 A, . . .?

Comment: @JimStewart prepare for this to be European style.

Comment: The downstairs breaker is not a master breaker although it appears to be bigger. What is a double-pole braker? How do I figure out the amperage on the circuit breakers (presumably the ones at which the circuit breakers trip)? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like they are both RCDs.

Comment: Can you see the second (third) RCD (metal olive-colored box)? Why need this one as well?