# Second circuit breaker downstairs

Tags: wiring

I just moved into an apartment and would like to do some work such as upgrade the wires to allow a greater amperage to flow through to prevent my appliances from tripping the circuit breakers when too many appliances are connected.

I have a circuit breaker upstairs. Originally there were also two circuit breakers downstairs, one servicing my own flat and another servicing my neighbor's flat.

However, some work was done and now there is a second circuit breaker attached to the former one servicing my apartment downstairs, so now I have two downstairs circuit breakers servicing my apartment in addition to the circuit breaker upstairs.

Can someone please explain to me what the point of a second circuit breaker downstairs might be? How is this second circuit breaker likely to modify the circuit?

(my circuit breaker is the white one on the left, and the second one downstairs is attached to my circuit breaker alone is the one to its left, in the shade, and you can see its on off button if you enlarge the image):

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Where is this flat: city and country?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two circuit breakers, how to determine which one jumps](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/124956/two-circuit-breakers-how-to-determine-which-one-jumps)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. There is a second RCD downstairs. The other post describes a differeng situation.